# Blender UV unwrapping causes texture to repeat in UDK material

Tags: mesh, materials, export

I've made pillow kinda thing and unwrapped In blender and I imported my mesh to UDK,applied a material:

[image]

The material splits, but I don't want that to happen, I want to cover the mesh with only big texture, like this one for example:

[image]

How do I that?

Comment: You probably used wrong method to unwrap your model, can you add a screenshot of the UV map?

Comment: @Denis Well I don't add my textures to my models in blender I only Unwrap them and import to UDK and add the textures there

Comment: I have flagged this as a cross post of [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102715/blender-uv-unwrapping-causes-texture-to-repeat-in-udk-material) GameDev.SE question, since it primarily concerns settings in UDK.